# LeetCode 1638: Count Substrings That Differ by One Character

Tags: beginner, algorithm, c, programming-challenge, strings

I'm posting a solution for LeetCode's "Count Substrings That Differ by One Character". If you'd like to review, please do. Thank you!

#### [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-substrings-that-differ-by-one-character/)

> Given two strings s and t, find the number of ways you can choose a
> non-empty substring of s and replace a single character by a different
> character such that the resulting substring is a substring of t. In
> other words, find the number of substrings in s that differ from some
> substring in t by exactly one character.
>
> For example, the underlined substrings in "[compute](http:///)r" and "[computa](http:///)tion"
> only differ by the 'e'/'a', so this is a valid way.
>
> Return the number of substrings that satisfy the condition above.
>
> A substring is a contiguous sequence of characters within a string.

#### Example 1:

[image]

#### Example 2:

[image]

#### Constraints:

- 1 <= s.length, t.length <= 100
- s and t consist of lowercase English letters only.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const size_t getCounts(
    const char *source,
    const char *target,
    size_t s_index,
    size_t t_index
) {
    size_t counter = 0;
    size_t prev = 0;
    size_t curr = 0;

    while (s_index < strlen(source) && t_index < strlen(target)) {
        ++curr;

        if (source[s_index] != target[t_index]) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = 0;
        }

        counter += prev;
        ++s_index;
        ++t_index;
    }

    return counter;
}

static const int countSubstrings(
    const char *source,
    const char *target
) {
    size_t counters = 0;

    for (size_t s_index = 0; s_index < strlen(source); ++s_index) {
        counters += getCounts(source, target, s_index, 0);
    }

    for (size_t t_index = 1; t_index < strlen(target); ++t_index) {
        counters += getCounts(source, target, 0, t_index);
    }

    return counters;
}

int main() {
    printf ("%i \n", countSubstrings("aba", "baba"));
    printf ("%i \n", countSubstrings("ab", "bb"));
    printf ("%i \n", countSubstrings("a", "a"));
    printf ("%i \n", countSubstrings("abe", "bbc"));
    printf ("%i \n", countSubstrings("abeaskdfjpoirgfjifjwkdafjaksld",
                                     "fqowuerflqfdjcasdjkvlfkjqheofkjsdjfasldkf"));
    return 0;
}
```

#### Outputs:

```
6 
3 
0 
10 
1314
```

Comment: Your examples do not really help  because the underlines are not visible (at least not in my browser).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks nice, and you got the right algorithm.

Still, there are problems and additional ideas:

1. The `const`-qualifier on the two functions return-value is ignored. Didn't your compiler warn?
2. Denoting the start of a string-slice by pointer to start of the whole string and offset into it is cumbersome and inefficient. Just give a pointer to the start of the slice.
3. You are playing [Shlemiel The Painter](http://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter) with all four `strlen()`-calls in your loops. The compiler might be able to hoist it four you, or it might not.

   If it cannot, at least those in `countSubstrings()` are cheaper by some constant factor than the calls to a fixed `getCounts()`, and thus don't influence your codes big-oh.
   But those in `getCounts()` turn the function from linear to quadratic, and thus the algorithm from quadratic to cubic.

   What I don't get is why you ask for the strings length at all.
   Just substitute `!s[n]` for `strlen(s) == n`.
4. Either `int` is always big enough, and should be used throughout, or it isn't,
   and you have to play it safe by using `size_t`.
5. By the way, the problem is symmetric in its two arguments. That can be used.

And that was all I found.

```
static int getCounts(const char* a, const char* b) {
    int prev = 0;
    int curr = 0;
    int r = 0;
    for (; *a && *b; r += prev) {
        ++curr;
        if (*a++ != *b++) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = 0;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

static int manyCounts(const char* a, const char* b) {
    int r = 0;
    while (*a)
        r += getCounts(a++, b);
    return r;
}

int countSubstrings(const char * a, const char * b) {
    return !*a ? 0 : manyCounts(a + 1, b) + manyCounts(b, a);
}
```